# Tensorflow computation time drop with increasing model size

Tags: tensorflow

When running my experiments, I noticed a strange drop in computation time using tensorflow with GPU support. With each iteration (1000 learning steps) the model size is increased  by 200 hidden neurons (simple fully connected nn with one hidden layer). Now I measured the time it takes for each iteration and noticed this drop at the same spot for different versions of the algorithm. So this can have nothing to do with some external event on the machine, as the experiments were run successively. Is there something tensorflow can exploit after reaching a certain model size?
[Plotted Time w.r.t iterations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YvLf.png)

Comment: can you share some more implementation details like what kind of optimizer you are using and a bit more about the architecture?  For example, is the architecture a *series* of dense layers or *parallel* set or is there an easing function to smooth the addition?

Comment: sure, I am using the built in Adam Optimizer from tensorflow. The model basically consists of two dense layers which are increased in size each iteration by simply concatenating a new weight matrix. So the model has the same amount of layers throughout the process. thanks for your help!

Comment: what do the different colours in the graph mean?

Comment: These are just different modifications of the algorithm which have nothing to do with the model architecture itself.

Comment: If you are using a sparse matrix *and* you are using an L1 regularizer, then perhaps around iteration 32 you cross a threshold where your L1 finally makes your sparse matrix sparse enough for matrix operation optimization.  That's all I got.  According to the docs https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/AdamOptimizer Adam uses a sparse matrix, so that may very well be it.  Try again using Momentum Gradient or Vanilla Gradient.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that sounds very convincing!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a sparse matrix and you are using an L1 regularizer, then perhaps around iteration 32 you cross a threshold where your L1 finally makes your sparse matrix sparse enough for matrix operation optimization.

According to the docs tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/AdamOptimizer Adam uses a sparse matrix, so that may very well be it. Try again using Momentum Gradient or Vanilla Gradient.